# load motorhawk DLL in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dll, loadlibrary

I am really not an expert in programming so I already apologize for the stupid questions I have.

I am trying to load the dll for a control board (motorhawk from pc-control.co.uk) in this way

```
loadlibrary('hawk.dll', 'hawkdll.h', 'alias', 'hawk')
```

if then I check wheter the library has been loaded with

```
libisloaded('hawk')
```

I get a positive response. However if I ask for the functions I have just loaded

```
libfunctions('hawk')
```

I do not get any function, with an error saying lib.hawk method not found.

I think the problem may be on the way the header is written

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////
//          hawkdll.h
//        revision 1.3
//
//    All copyright PC Control Ltd. 2010
//      
///////////////////////////////////////////////
// DLL Function type definitions

// system defs
typedef int (*Type_Sys_Initialise)();               // find all devices connected and open USB paths to them
typedef int (*Type_Sys_GetMotorHawkCount)();        // find number of motor hawks connected
typedef int (*Type_Sys_GetSwitchingHawkCount)();    // find number of switching hawks connected
typedef int (*Type_Sys_GetServoHawkCount)();        // find number of servo hawks connected
typedef int (*Type_Sys_CloseAllDevices)();          // close all open paths to USB devices

// motor hawk defs
typedef int (*Type_Motor_SetType)(int devnum, int type);                // choose motor type (stepper or DC Motors)
typedef int (*Type_Motor_RunSteps)(int devnum, int steps);              // set the number of steps to execute
typedef int (*Type_Motor_SetDCMotors)(int devnum, int M1Speed, int M1Dir, int M2Speed, int M2Dir);      // set the speed and direction of both DC motors
typedef int (*Type_Motor_GetDCMotors)(int devnum, int *M1Speed, int *M1Dir, int *M2Speed, int *M2Dir);  // get the speed and direction of both DC motors from the specified board
typedef int (*Type_Motor_GetType)(int devnum, int *motor_type);                                         // get the type of motor currently configured for from the specified board
typedef int (*Type_Motor_GetStepper)(int devnum, int *direction, int *interval, int *step_mode, int *power, int *steps, int *run_mode, int *paused);            // get the current stepper motor settings from the specified board
typedef int (*Type_Motor_GetStepsRemaining)(int devnum, int *steps_remaining);          // get the current steps remaining from the specified board
typedef int (*Type_Motor_SetDigitalOutputs)(int devnum, int outputs);                   // set the digital outputs
typedef int (*Type_Motor_GetDigitalOutputs)(int devnum, int *outputs);                  // get the current settings of the digital outputs
typedef int (*Type_Motor_GetDigitalInputs)(int devnum, int *inputs);                    // get the current digital inputs
typedef int (*Type_Motor_SetLimitEnables)(int devnum, int m1_forward, int m1_reverse, int m2_forward, int m2_reverse);          // set the limit switch enables
typedef int (*Type_Motor_GetLimitEnables)(int devnum, int *m1_forward, int *m1_reverse, int *m2_forward, int *m2_reverse);      // get the current limit switch enable settings
typedef int (*Type_Motor_SetStepper)(int devnum, int direction, int interval, int step_mode, int power);                    // configure the stepper motor
typedef int (*Type_Motor_PauseStepper)(int devnum);                                     // temporarily pause the stepper motor
typedef int (*Type_Motor_ResumeStepper)(int devnum);                                    // resume running of the stepper motor
typedef int (*Type_Motor_StopStepper)(int devnum);                                      // stop the stepper motor and clear any remaining steps
typedef int (*Type_Motor_SetRunMode)(int devnum, int run_mode);                         // set the stepper running mode (once or continuous)
typedef int (*Type_Motor_ResetBoard)(int devnum);                                       // reset board

// switching hawk defs
typedef int (*Type_Switching_SetOutputs)(int devnum, int outputs);      // set the outputs
typedef int (*Type_Switching_GetOutputs)(int devnum, int *outputs);     // get the current outputs

// servo hawk defs
typedef int (*Type_Servo_SetServos)(int devnum, int Servo1, int Servo2, int Servo3, int Servo4, int Servo5, int Servo6, int Servo7, int Servo8);            // set the servos
typedef int (*Type_Servo_GetServos)(int devnum, int *Servo1, int *Servo2, int *Servo3, int *Servo4, int *Servo5, int *Servo6, int *Servo7, int *Servo8);    // get the current servo positions
typedef int (*Type_Servo_SetOutputs)(int devnum, int outputs);      // set the outputs
typedef int (*Type_Servo_GetOutputs)(int devnum, int *outputs);     // get the current outputs

///////////////////////////////////////////////
// other defs
#define STEP_MODE_FULL  1
#define STEP_MODE_HALF  2

#define POWER_ZERO          1
#define POWER_FRACTIONAL    2
#define POWER_MAX           3

#define MHK_STOPPED         0
#define MHK_FORWARD         1       // direction of DC motors
#define MHK_REVERSE         2

#define TYPE_STEPPER    0           // motor hawk is driving a stepper motor
#define TYPE_DCMOTORS   1           // motor hawk is driving two DC motors

#define STEPPER_RUN_ONCE        0   // run the specified steps once
#define STEPPER_RUN_CONTINUOUS  1   // run stepper continuously
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks for your help

Davide

Comment: Whats the error and what are you trying?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd suggest you change your load call to

```
[notfound, warnings] = loadlibrary('hawk.dll', 'hawkdll.h', 'alias', 'hawk')
```

The variable `notfound` will list any functions mentioned in the header file but not found in the dll.  `warnings` may provide some insight as well.

One possible problem is if hawk.dll is a c++ library, matlab only supports c style linkage.  If this is the case, you can still write the dll in c++, but you have to add `extern "C"` to each function definition and prototype, and recompile the dll.  If you do not have access to the source code, you will need to create a wrapper DLL with `extern "C"` functions that then call the c++ function.

You can use a tool such as [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to determine what functions hawk.dll exports, and if they are c or c++ style linkage.